# Import data from SQL Server table into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't get this SQL statement right. I want to select band emails into another table but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
INSERT INTO submitted (mail)
    SELECT
        submitted.bandid,
        band.mail,
        band.id
    FROM 
        band
    WHERE 
        submitted.bandid = band.id
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You're saying that you want to insert into just one column (`mail`) in your new table - but you're selecting **three** columns from the original table - that won't work. **Either** define the **three** columns you want to insert those values into in your destination table, **OR** just select the **one** column you want to actually use to insert data from the source table

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you had specified 1 column to INSERT INTO but your SELECT query contained 3 columns, also the tables in your weren't joined:

```
INSERT INTO submitted (mail) 
SELECT
band.mail
FROM band 
INNER JOIN submitted ON submitted.bandid = band.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the error message you're getting, but I suspect the problem is that you only have one column specified in the `INSERT` part of the statement, but the `SELECT` part returns many columns.

[This w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) has a good example of how this query should be structured:

> Copy only some columns from one table into another table:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
> SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
> FROM table1
> WHERE condition;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want `update`, not `insert`:

```
UPDATE s
    SET mail = b.mail
    FROM submitted s JOIN
         band b
         ON s.bandid = b.id;
```

`insert` inserts new *rows* into the table.  `update` updates columns in *existing* rows.